When trying to get interface name using Linux call if_indextoname, returned pointer is crashing
While trying to get interface name using below code, returned pointer p is crashing. Can someone help?
#include <net/if.h>

char *p = NULL, buf[IFNAMSIZ]='\0';
int i = 0;
for(i=0; i<50; i++)
{
    p = if_indextoname(i,buf);
    if(p == NULL)
        continue;
    printf("p = %s",*p);
}

Here value of  IFNAMSIZ is 16 & defined in if.h file.
Though pointer address is valid, unable to access its value.
I tried initialising the pointer and the buffer & added null check before printing pointer p. But it didn't help

The POSIX specification for if_indextoname say that the size of the buffer must be at least IF_NAMESIZE bytes. What is IFNAMSIZ? Please [edit] your question to show us a [mre].

Both have the same value

The initializer for buf is wrong. It should be something like { 0 } or "". I don't think that's the problem though.

I tried changing but this also didn't help.

The printf call is wrong. *p should be p. It would also be a good idea to print a newline character.

Or use buf in the printf() call. The only putpose of p is as an error indicator.

You don't even need p, just use if (if_indextoname(i, buf) == NULL)

Buf has valid value. But  Same code is working for 32 bit compiler. Issue is seen only on 64 bit compiler

Now when it's pointed out, it kind of stands out... The expression *p is the same as *(p + 0) which is the same as p[0]. As you now should see, that's a single character, not a pointer to a null-terminated string as expected by %s. Mismatched format and argument leads to undefined behavior. In fact, doesn't your compiler warn you about this? Then you need to enable more warnings. And treat warnings as errors.

Unable to print char by char also.

You don't need to print "char by char". You just need to pass the correct parameter value to match the %s printf specifier, i.e. printf("p = %s\n", p); or printf("buf = %s\n", buf);.

It didn't help. Since issue is seen only on 64 bit machine, checking whether any changes went in lately

Same pointer is working in other modules. In issue stat, Binary permissions are proper. But not sure why it is crashing in particular module.
